# use css to make div in the same height

Tags: html, css

hello i have a 3 texts with a background images the idea is to make the divs in the same height even if one text is longer than the others,
so for now i'm just doing a padding-top for every text but its not practice to do this, do you guys have another alternative ?

this is my code :

```
.vc_custom_1617813617301 {
    padding-top: 100px !important;
    background-image: url(http://s865417502.onlinehome.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Rectangle-8.png?id=8361) !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

also the texts are in a div with a class called : `block-t` i have tried to setup a `padding-top : 100%` to make them with the same height but its not working

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are expected to present an MCVE of your problem **in the question itself**. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. That being said, look into flex box or CSS grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best and modern way is flexbox

you just need to set the `display:flex` to your parent `element` and use `flex-basis` for the children

for example:

I hope help you

```css
.parent {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: left;
      width: 100%;}
.parent .child {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;/* Suggested */
      align-items: center; /* Suggested */
      flex-basis: 33%;/* you can use for example calc(33.33% - 16px) if you need to set a space between them too */
      padding: 8px; /* Suggested */
      margin: 8px; /* Suggested */
      background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>a long text : Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores deleniti repellendus temporibus laborum nobis itaque neque, ratione tenetur cum illum quae est </p>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>text : porro fugit mollitia corrupti quam corporis reiciendis. Necessitatibus?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>text : porro fugit mollitia corrupti quam corporis reiciendis. Necessitatibus?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```